# Text box conditional formatting coloring

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

I've worked out that I can link a text box to a cell. (Create the text box, add text, replace text with an equals sign `=`, and then click on the cell I want it to reference. So far so good.

However it does seem that I am unable to change the colour of the ink in the text box to match the conditional formatting in the cell, it always seem to default to black.

I don't want to use macros. Is there a way for the text box to reflect the colour on the text in the cell (with the conditional formatting) is referencing?

Comment: Depends on how your text box is positioned. There maybe a way to change the background color of the textbox, but not the text. But the method I have in mind will raise the question of the requirement of the textbox. You could position the text box aligned over some cells, put the conditional formatting on the cells, keep the background color of the textbox transparent. This way the text box will reflect the background cells color.

Comment: @Firee Thanks, but I already thought of that. The textbox is part of a chart and that is likely to get moved (by a third party), so any location based ideas are off the cards.

Comment: @Máté Juhász  I like your candour!

Comment: Did you check the camera function?

Comment: @Firee That's a good idea, but I need the colour to change depending on the values (green - low, amber - middle, red - high) And you can only apply one style to a camera picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no way for that without macros.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linked picture, it has some formatting limitations, but may work for your application. Copy the conditionally formatted cell, paste as a linked picture. The picture will change when the cell changes.